# How to set mouse hover over progress bar in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I'm using progress bar for `gantt` chart in my project and is going good. Now I need to show time and details when mouse is placed over it without click. Is it possible and have anyone done something similar before?

Comment: I think you mean 'Tooltip' not mouse hover! If your information are fixed, just write them in value of 'Tooltip' property, if not you can bind the content from backend.

Comment: i think i need both

Comment: For customizing the mouse hover you need to define a style for your progressbar. If you can not solve it, let me know so I can write the answer for you.

Comment: I couldn't and please solve if you can. And describe it for me as am a beginner it will be helpful for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a StackPanel for the ToolTip to show both Time and details when the mouse is over.By default, when the mouse over the control, and its ToolTip will pop-up, the below is my processbar with tooltip:

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="MyBar" Width="200" Height="20" Value="60">
        <ProgressBar.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBox Text="Here is the details" Background="LightBlue" Height="50" Width="120"></TextBox>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}}" Background="Azure" Height="50" Width="120"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ToolTip>
        </ProgressBar.ToolTip>
    </ProgressBar>
```

The result picture is like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is for Tooltip:

Just write:

```
<ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="75" Tooltip="Your desired text" />
```

or bind your text:

```
<ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="75" Tooltip="{Binding, path=YourText}" />
```

For hover use `IsMouseOver` property:

```
 <ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="75">
    <ProgressBar .Style>
        <Style TargetType="ProgressBar">       
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    --your desired code--
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ProgressBar.Style>
</ProgressBar>
```